# What are "secrets" and "agents" in wireless error messages?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, kubuntu

Kubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo Thinkpad 560.  I've been having lots of wireless problems, among them a refusal to auto-connect to my office wifi.  Every time I suspend, hibernate, or restart I have to enter the wifi password all over again.  This doesn't happen with my home wifi.

Whenever I open the configuration dialog for this connection, I get a popup error

```
Failed to get secrets for OfficeNetwork

No agents were available for this request
```

Under the configuration for the connection, I have "Automatically connect to this network when it is available" selected.  Under the "Wi-Fi Security" tab of the config dialog, there's a place for the password.  When I enter the password there and save, it's no longer there when I reopen the dialog.

I'd like to troubleshoot this myself, but I can't figure out the error message.  In particular, what are the "secrets" and "agents" referred to, and what's wrong with them?  More general advice is also appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Secret" is a password – and a generic term for a network's password, a certificate key's unlock passphrase, a smartcard's PIN code, etc.

"Agent", in this case, is a helper program which does something on the service's behalf. In this case, the NetworkManager service cannot directly connect to your graphical session and display password prompts there (because it's a service). Therefore, NetworkManager expects KDE to connect *back* to NM, wait for password requests, and display the prompts on NM's behalf.

In addition to displaying interactive prompts, the agent also deals with storing passwords in KWallet (or GNOME Keyring, or...) and retrieving them when NetworkManager asks for them. So check KWalletManager to see if it's properly storing the passwords.

(I don't know which KDE component usually acts as the agent for NM; it might be part of plasma-nm. Running `nmcli agent` via terminal, or starting the GNOME Keyring-based `nm-applet`, would provide a temporary alternative.)

Another option might be to open the connection's settings (in `kde5-nm-connection-editor` or the generic `nm-connection-editor`), and change the connection to be system-wide (aka "available to all users"). That way the WiFi password will be stored in `/etc` and always available to NM (but no longer encrypted).